# how to convert xml as another xml using php

Tags: php, xml

I want to convert one xml  to another xml.for example if xml tag as string,

```
<book>
<title>test</test>
<isbn>1234567890</isbn>
<author>test</author>
<publisher>xyz publishing</publisher>
</book>
```

i want to convert above xml as,

```
<b00>
<t001>test</t001>
<a001>1234567890</a001>
<a002>test</a002>
<p001>xyz publishing </p001>
</b00>
```

how to convert xml using php

Comment: ya its possible in str_replace. Is there is any another way to convert it.I am using onix xml format for book upload process. In onix xml they use two types of xml tags for example <ISBN> similar tag they use  <b004>. Like that there are several tags.

Comment: Google for XSLT and then see how far you can get with it. But first, fix your invalid XML.

Comment: thank you Gordon, i will use XSLT for conversion.

Comment: off topic: why would anyone design an XML schema that looked like the second code block? I presume this is an existing schema that you've been asked to map to, but honestly, that is a monstrosity. XML is not the neatest or most efficient of formats, but one of the key reasons for using it is because it XML allows you to give your data sensible field names. If you're going to name them `t001` and `a002`, it kinda defeats the point. You may as well have have used a flat CSV file.

Comment: can you please review the answers you have been given and either accept the one that helped you most/solved your problem or point out why none of the answers solved your problem. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use XSLT for the conversion.

#### PHP Code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('/path/to/your/stylesheet.xsl');
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsl->importStyleSheet($doc);
$doc->load('/path/to/your/file.xml');
echo $xsl->transformToXML($doc);
```

#### XSLT File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <b00><xsl:apply-templates/></b00>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <t001><xsl:value-of select="."/></t001>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="isbn">
        <a001><xsl:value-of select="."/></a001>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="author">
        <a002><xsl:value-of select="."/></a002>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="publisher">
        <p001><xsl:value-of select="."/></p001>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```